# Can't add hover property to custom HTML mail

Tags: java, css, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to do a hover effect on an: `<a href...` class.
I have 2 `<a href`, one is a standard link and the other one has to be a button.

`.btnMail:hover 
 #btn:hover`

This works on GMAIL, but not on Outlook Web. The only way I got the :hover effect to work on outlook was doing just an `a:hover` but this affects all `<a` tags.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false, "utf-8");

String htmlMsg = ""
        + "<style type=\"text/css\">" +

        "  .btnMail {\r\n" + 
        "  background-color: #007bff;\r\n" +
        "  cursor: pointer;\r\n" + 
        "  border: none;\r\n" +
        "  border-radius: 4px;\r\n" + 
        "  text-decoration: none;\r\n" + 
        "  text-decoration-color: white !important;" + 
        "  color: white !important;\r\n" + 
        "  padding: 15px 32px;\r\n" + 
        "  text-align: center;\r\n" +
        "  display: inline-block;\r\n" + 
        "  font-size: 18px;\r\n" +
        "  }\r\n" +

        "  .btnMail:hover{\r\n" +
        "  background-color: #0069d9 !important;\r\n" +
        "  }\r\n"

        + "</style>"
        + "<div style=\"width:100%;height:100%;\">"
        + "<div style=\"margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:550px;\">"
        + "<h3>" + messages.getMessage("mail.reset", null, locale) + "</h3>"
        + "<div>" + messages.getMessage("mail.hello", null, locale) + " " + restoreUser.getUsername() + ", <br><br>"
        + messages.getMessage("mail.body", null, locale) + "</div><br>"

        + "<a id=\"btn\" class=\"btnMail\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" href=\"" + tokenLink +"\">"

        + messages.getMessage("mail.button", null, locale) + "</a><br>"
        + "<div>" + messages.getMessage("mail.validtime", null, locale) + "<br><br>"
        + messages.getMessage("mail.thanks", null, locale) + "<br>"
        + messages.getMessage("header.companyname", null, locale) +"</div>"
        + "<br>"
        + "<hr/>"
        + "<div style=\"font-size:12px;\">" + messages.getMessage("mail.link", null, locale) +"<br>"

        + "<a href=\"" + tokenLink +" \">" + tokenLink +"</a></div>"

        + "</div>"
        + "</div>"
        + "";

mimeMessage.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");
```

https://gyazo.com/e8f3a7105b66e6da61ed957e2437cc4d

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please precise what is your request? And also, what is the language you use?

Comment: @Vega If you check the <a tag already has a class and also an id, the probem is that it works for the standard style but it doesent work with the :hover. Also, this code works perfectly at GMAL

Comment: Even when using a web browser email companies try to explicitly block this stuff, what if you showed a link and then on hover changed the link, they don't want people doing misleading stuff like that in an email. I would more say Gmail is wrong and should not be doing it than outlook is wrong, as allowing people to be misled is not good email users are your common everyday folk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many css elements that do not perform well in email clients. 
Hover is one if the elements without a broad support. 
This element along with support information for other ones [can be found here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/any-hover/), amongst other resources.

As for your html in your example. Keep in mind that many spam filters are looking for poor html syntax as a sign of spammy content. You should consider adding html, head and body tags to your message.